# 1.9.2.1 Disable Paypal Express

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express, paypal-standard

since magento version 1.9.iDontKnow.* paypal wps ist not available without paypal express.

The problem is that the paypal express review page is required to pass, which is totally abusing the customer checkout process from my point of view.

I need to get back to the prior checkout workflow of paypal without beeing redirected to the paypal express ugly review page.

So in detail/steps:

- Customer goes to /checkout/onepage
- Customer enters billing/shipping, chooses paypal and shipping method
- Customer gets to the review (last step)
- Customer gets redirected to paypal after clicking on "place order"
- Customer sees the success page after the paypal gateway

Is it possible to configure or hack back the old behaviour as described above?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using the following extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-standard-payment-revival-27041.html